# Consume onetopic from multithread kafkalisteners in spring

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Hi I have a one topic and I consume message this topic with help of  @KafkaListener annotation in spring
I want to consume topic from multi threaded listener,how can I achive this?

There is a property in ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory to set concurency but is this right way?
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.setConcurrency(3),one listener and three different threads to consume one topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that will create 3 threads, but the topic needs at least 3 partitions; you can't consume from a single partition will multiple consumers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple listeners, then add concurrency as a property of `@KafkaListener`. For example,

```
    @KafkaListener(id = "consumer1", topics = {"topic1","topic2"}, groupId = "group1", concurrency = "4")
    public void consumeLog1(){
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "consumer2", topics = {"topic2","topic3"}, groupId = "group1", concurrency = "5")
    public void consumeLog2(){
    }
```

`consumer1` will create 4 `KafkaConsumers` and `consumer2` will create 5 `KafkaConsumers`. And they will listen to their assigned topics.

If you have only one `@KafkaListener` then add the default concurrency as a property.

```
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency=3
```

This value will be overridden by the concurrency value in `@KafkaListener`.

Comment: in this case consumer1 listen topic1 with 4 different threads if topic1 has 4 partitions am I right?

Comment: in the case of consumer1 4 consumer thread will be created and they will listen to topic1 and topic2. Lets assume, only tpic1 exists and it has 4 partitions, then yes 4 consumer threads will listen to 4 partitions concurrently. If there are more than 4 partitions then some thread will switch between 2 or more partitions. If threre are less that 4 partitions, then some thread will remain idle.